# How to define a multiple composition function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is there a way to define a Haskell function that takes a (some kind of collection) of functions and produces a single function: their composition from right to left?

I tried:

**`foldr ($)`**

but this only accepts a list of functions whose result has the same type as that of their argument:

**`foldr ($) :: a -> [a -> a] -> a`**

So, I can do:

**`foldr ($) 5 [(+) 1, (*) 2]`**
and this produces the correct result 11

However trying to evaluate this:

**`foldr ($) "hello" [(+) 1, length]`**

produces the error below:

ERROR - Type error in list

`*** Expression     : [(1 +),length]
*** Term           : length
*** Type           : [a] -> Int
*** Does not match : Int -> Int`

Comment: The real problem here is that you can't even have a list of items of different type in Haskell....  So `[(+ 1), length]` alone can't be used.  You will have to rethink the approach.

Comment: You will need a custom `FunList a b` list of functions starting from `a` and ending with `b` to define that composition. This requires existential types. E.g. `data Funlist a b where Nil :: FunList a a ; Cons :: (a->b) -> FunList b c -> FunList a c` using GADTs.

Comment: Or equivalently (but already existing), a [thrist](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11558339/1346276). But by that, a quite similar question has already been answered.

Comment: There has been a lot of activity on a [subsequent question addressing the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593237/what-would-the-type-of-a-list-of-cascading-functions-be).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always, let's put type annotations everywhere.

```
-- foldr ($) "hello" [(+) 1, length]
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
"hello" :: [Char]
(+) 1 :: Num a => a -> a
length :: [a] -> Int
[(+) 1, length] :: ?!
```

Native Haskell lists cannot contain items of different types.

So let's back up a step. I'll use `<` and `>` to denote "the list-ish thing we want." We don't want a collection of randomly-typed things. `< (+) 1, length >` is okay, but `< length, (+) 1 >` is not, or rather we'd need an instance `Num [a]`. Similarly if we have more than two items: each item's type is necessarily related to its neighbors. Furthermore, the type of the overall list is related only to the types of the first and last members: what's the starting and ending type?

We can do this with GADTs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module SO26565306 where

data F a b where
  FNil :: F a a
  (:&) :: (b -> c) -> F a b -> F a c

infixr 5 :&

runF :: F a b -> a -> b
runF FNil = id
runF (f :& fs) = f . runF fs

f :: F [a] Int
f = (+) 1 :& length :& FNil

ghci> runF f "hello"
6
```

The value `f` is the implementation of your desired `< (+) 1, length >` "list".

There's some further elaboration of `F` possible--`Functor` and `Category` instances, for example--but I don't really see much use for it. All we've done is artificially impose a data structure on ordinary function composition. We can't even use GHC's [overloaded list notation](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/OverloadedLists), which isn't (yet?) sufficiently flexible. Furthermore, interposing all the GADT constructors will block optimizations, almost certainly including list fusion. (I haven't experimented or thought through it carefully.)

### Answering Your Question

Yes, it's possible to define a Haskell function that takes a collection of functions, of varying but composable types, and produces their composition. The collection type I've demonstrated needs the `GADTs` extension, which is [not available in Hugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158023/how-to-use-gadts-in-hugs), the compiler you seem to be using. Furthermore, you can't really do much with the collection. I've not proved it, but I'll assert that there's nothing you can do with a value of type `F a b` that you can't do with a value of type `a -> b`, other than decomposing it into its component functions by pattern-matching.

In other words, what you're asking about is indeed expressible in Haskell, it's just not clear that there's any advantage to doing it in this way.

### Other Questions

As we've discussed in the comments, it seems you're looking for a Haskell analogy for Clojure transducers. Would you like to open a new question on that topic? It's a bit more precise and focused differently than this one.

### The Bottom Line

Why not just use `((+) 1) . length`?

Comment: "Bottom line: why not just use `((+) 1) . length`?"  This is the correct answer.  `f . g . h` *is* the "list of functions" `[h, g, f]` that you are looking for.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't mean to be snarky. @Dimitre Novatchev looks to be an expert in a number of languages/fields that use data structures differently than in Haskell. I'm not confident that my answer (yet) addresses his real question.

Comment: AFAICT you can't do anything with the desired, generalized, `[h, g, f]` that you can't do with `f . g . h` (i.e. all you can do is apply the functions in a sequence), so I think your answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @TomEllis and Christian Conkle: `Why not just use ((+) 1) . length?` Well, I will have an unknown number of composable functions, so I can't type any such expression in advance. Of course, if I have a general Haskell interpreter, I could generate the expression as a string and evaluate it with the interpreter. I am not sure if such facility exists, but even if it did, this wouldn't be too efficient.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: If you have an unknown number of composable functions please edit your question to say how they arise and how you know the types match up.  I suspect we will be able to clarify how to use composition to solve your problem.

Comment: @TomEllis, I am given a list of `foldl` - like function definitions. Each such function is essentially a `foldl`, but it has a transducer `(Result, Input -> Result) -> (Result, Input -> Result)` and a separate reducing function `Result, Input -> Result` . Applying the transducer on the provided reducing function gives us the reducing function that `foldl` uses. The idea is to compose all transducers (take each from its foldl definition) and leave the reducing function only of the last `foldl` definition. A known property of composing two transducers is that the result is also a transducer.

Comment: Do you literally have a list of them?  If so they all must be the same type so you can indeed just use `foldr ($)`.  If not, you're going to have to explain in more detail where they come from.  I suggest editing your question so these comments don't get too long.

Comment: Maybe you should post a new question about your transducer example--it seems substantially different than this one. (The types don't vary?) You might want to check out the packages [`foldl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl) and [`machines`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines). (Oh, also, do you mean `(Result, Input) -> Result`, which is isomorphic to `Result -> Input -> Result`?)

Comment: @ChristianConkle: I believe Rich Hickey's original presentation of transformers used examples with non-rigourous types.  Several commentators have tried to unpick them and state more rigourous types, e.g. here http://conscientiousprogrammer.com/blog/2014/08/07/understanding-cloure-transducers-through-types/

Comment: @TomEllis: I was just reading the [/r/haskell discussion linked in that post](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2cv6l4/clojures_transducers_are_perverse_lenses/). It may also be relevant to the new question. (P.S. Tekmo = Gabriel Gonzalez; i.e. the authors of both libraries I linked to are active in the Reddit discussion.)

Comment: @TomEllis and Christian Conkle: Here are some links to transducers material: Rich Hickey's "Transducers" talk on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mTbuzafcII and "Understanding Transducers" by Elben Shira: http://elbenshira.com/blog/understanding-transducers/  . Is there a facility in Haskell that allows a function to be defined that has variable number of arguments with slightly different types?

Comment: Sorry, that question is too vague.  I suggest opening a new question.

Comment: @TomEllis, OK, lets close this. I just wanted to get an idea whether or not such thing is expressible in Haskell. it seems there is no clear positive answer.

Comment: No, I think there is a clear answer to the stated question--"yes"--and I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell List only allows elements of the same type. So just like you can't have

```
["one", 2]
```

because `"one"` is a `String` and `2` is an `Int`. You also can't have

```
[(+) 1, length]
```

Because `(+) 1` is a `Int -> Int` and `length` is a `[a] -> Int`